# Jquery for each in HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, foreach, getjson

I have an HTML string, which I get from using `getJSON` method. I want to iterate through this whole string, find all divs with class `product-review` and push its content to my array. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Maybe a hidden div in the webpage, then appending the string to it, and parsing the content of it.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: `$(htmlstring).find('.product-review')` <- like that, jQuery parses HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st :**  you need to select the `'div.product-review'` by using `.find()`

```
$(response).find('div.product-review')
```

**2nd:** you need to loop through them and push its content to the array

```
var contentarray = [];
$(response).find('div.product-review').each(function(){
    var ThisIt = $(this);
    contentarray.push(ThisIt.text());
});
console.log(contentarray);
```

Comment: @deviant you're Welcome Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add that string into a hidden element, then find in that hidden element all divs

```
var YOUR_CONTENT=$(".hiddelElement div.product-review").text();
```